# Spark NoSuchMethodError on SQLContext.sql (Spark 1.6.0 on Cloudera 5.8.0)

Tags: java, apache-spark, cloudera

I am trying to use Spark SQL from a java program, Where the dependency in pom.xml points to Spark version 1.6.0. Below is the program

```
package spark_test;

import java.util.List;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext;

public class MyTest {
private static SparkConf sparkConf;

public static void main(String[] args) {        
    String warehouseLocation = args[0];
    sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Hive Test").setMaster("local[*]")
            .set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation);

    JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
    SQLContext sc = new HiveContext(ctx.sc());

    System.out.println(" Current Tables: ");

    DataFrame results = sc.sql("show tables");
    results.show();
}
}
```

However, I am getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame; I am creating a flat jar and running the jar from command line

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/cloudera/workspace/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/cloudera/workspace/PortalHandlerTest.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/cloudera/workspace/SparkTest.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/home/cloudera/workspace/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/cloudera/workspace/JARs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.22.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
17/04/25 08:44:07 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.1.0
17/04/25 08:44:07 WARN SparkContext: Support for Java 7 is deprecated as of Spark 2.0.0
17/04/25 08:44:07 WARN SparkContext: Support for Scala 2.10 is deprecated as of Spark 2.1.0
17/04/25 08:44:08 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/04/25 08:44:08 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: cloudera
17/04/25 08:44:08 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: cloudera
17/04/25 08:44:08 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
17/04/25 08:44:08 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
17/04/25 08:44:08 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(cloudera); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(cloudera); groups with modify permissions: Set()
17/04/25 08:44:09 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 43850.
17/04/25 08:44:09 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
17/04/25 08:44:09 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
17/04/25 08:44:09 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
17/04/25 08:44:09 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
17/04/25 08:44:09 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-4199c353-4e21-4863-8b78-cfa280ce2de3
17/04/25 08:44:09 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 375.7 MB
17/04/25 08:44:09 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
17/04/25 08:44:09 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
17/04/25 08:44:09 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4041.
17/04/25 08:44:09 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://10.0.2.15:4041
17/04/25 08:44:10 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
17/04/25 08:44:10 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 41716.
17/04/25 08:44:10 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 10.0.2.15:41716
17/04/25 08:44:10 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
17/04/25 08:44:10 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 41716, None)
17/04/25 08:44:10 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.0.2.15:41716 with 375.7 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 41716, None)
17/04/25 08:44:10 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 41716, None)
17/04/25 08:44:10 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 41716, None)
Current Tables: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame;
at spark_test.MyTest.main(MyTest.java:31)
17/04/25 08:44:10 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
17/04/25 08:44:10 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.0.2.15:4041
17/04/25 08:44:10 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
17/04/25 08:44:10 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
17/04/25 08:44:10 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
17/04/25 08:44:10 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
17/04/25 08:44:10 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
17/04/25 08:44:10 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
17/04/25 08:44:10 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
17/04/25 08:44:10 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-93fca3d1-ff79-4d2b-b07f-a340c1a60416
```

Probably because my pom has spark version 1.6.0, but cloudera VM is running 2.1.0. spark-shell is running spark version 1.6.0 and working fine. How do I force the version to be 1.6.0 in my java program?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataFrame() was supplanted in Spark 2 by Dataset().  You'll need to import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset and use that if you're running a Spark 1.6 client with a Spark 2.1 server-side. Further information [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html).  Most of the API is similar from a developer experience perspective.  Honestly though you'd be a lot better off using at least Spark 2.0 dependencies in your client, if not the server version.

Comment: I compiled the same program under Spark 2.1.0 to use Datasets, but Can not read any Hive table through the program, even if  I set warehouse.dir and copied hive-site.xml in /usr/lib/spark/conf/ . Please look at the post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43619137/hive-tables-not-found-in-spark-sql-spark-sql-analysisexception-in-cloudera-vm)

Comment: That's a different problem.  I'll address it in your other post.

Comment: If your original question was resolved via the steps noted, please acknowledge.

Comment: Dataset is not available in Spark 1.6.0. So once compiled with Spark 2.1.0, Using Dataset did resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your logs show that you are running with Spark 2.1 libraries targeted against a 1.6.0 Spark Cluster. My guess is that your client and server libraries are not binary compatible. I would suggest that you use the same versions in your application as exists in the server to insure compatibility.

Comment: That is what my guess is. However, I am not sure how I can force my java program to run Spark 1.6.0 and not Spark 2.1.0. Also, I compiled the same program under Spark 2.1.0, but Can not read any Hive table through the program, even if  I set warehouse.dir and copied hive-site.xml in /usr/lib/spark/conf/ . Please look at the post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43619137/hive-tables-not-found-in-spark-sql-spark-sql-analysisexception-in-cloudera-vm)